# How to wait in selenium until user enter sms code on console?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

i have a script that scrapes a streaming platform, but I can't resolve the logic of my login method  Here's my method:

```
def login(self, url):
    '''Login into Vodafone'''

    with self.driver as driver:
        try:
            driver.get(url)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
            print('CONNECT TO VPN!!! (TURKEY).')
            time.sleep(15)
            driver.close()
            self.login(url)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "div[class='grid no-gutter--all profile-selector']").find_element_by_tag_name('a').click() # Here i choose profile
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "a[class='js-navigation-link navigation__link navigation__link--icon navigation__link--user navigation__user--menu navigation__link--menu js-navigation-user']").click() # Here i click on account menu
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "a[class='navigation__link navigation__link--secondary login-nudge__link']").click() # Click on login 
        time.sleep(2)
        # Send keys
        driver.find_element_by_name('Username').send_keys(self.user)
        driver.find_element_by_name('Password').send_keys(self.password)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='login__button']").click() # Click to receive sms code
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 180) # here i have my question
            verification = input('Waiting for SMS... you have 180 seconds: ').strip()
            if len(verification) != 4:
                verification = input('Must be 4 numbers: ').strip()
            driver.find_element_by_name('OtpCode').send_keys(verification)
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                        (By.XPATH, "//button[@id='confirm__button']"))).click()
                #driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='confirm__button']").click()
                time.sleep(8)
                print('LOGGIN SUCCESFUL!.')

                self.get_categories(driver)
            
            except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
                print('Code expired!.')
                time.sleep(10)
                driver.close()
                self.login(url)

        except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
            print('Timeout!!!.')
            driver.close()

            return None
```

My problem is in this piece of code:

```
try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 180) # here i have my question
        verification = input('Waiting for SMS... you have 180 seconds: ').strip()
        if len(verification) != 4:
            verification = input('Must be 4 numbers: ').strip()
        driver.find_element_by_name('OtpCode').send_keys(verification)
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.XPATH, "//button[@id='confirm__button']"))).click() #This is because button to confirm for a bit of seconds is blocked
            #driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='confirm__button']").click() # don't pay attention to this
            time.sleep(8)
            print('LOGGIN SUCCESFUL!.')

            self.get_categories(driver)

        except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
            print('Code expired!.')
            time.sleep(10)
            driver.close()
            self.login(url)

    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
        print('Timeout!!!.')
        driver.close()

        return None
```

After i choose profile and send my account data, i have 180 seconds to enter via console the sms code, the thing is that i want to handle the 180 seconds if the user does nothing during those seconds (closing the driver and returning None), how to do it? because WebDriverWait(driver, 180) doesn't work and i'm kinda new in selenium, can't find the solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any change in HTML dom when sms is entered into the input field

Answer (score 1):

```
from pytimedinput import timedInput
userText, timedOut = timedInput("Please, do enter something: ")
if(timedOut):
    print("Timed out when waiting for input.")
    print(f"User-input so far: '{userText}'")
else:
    print(f"User-input: '{userText}'")
```

https://pypi.org/project/pytimedinput/

python input method doesn't have any time out option use this library instead